# Combining plyr functions and xyplot from lattice

Tags: r, plyr, lattice, panels

I'm struggling to combine in a meaningful way `d_ply` and `xyplot` over a big database of sales, to plot two panels per week (one with a chart of the average price and one with cumulated quantities).

My action plan is to prepare the dataframe, subsetting it and use the subset with a combination of `xyplot` (to create the panels per week) and `d_ply` (to apply xyplot over all the different product codes on sale).

Let's assume I have the following type of dataframe (dummy code) and useful values to subset it:

```
 library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
library(plyr)
set.seed(1)
mydf <- as.data.frame(cbind(COD=rep(c("AB", "CD", "EF", "GH", "IJ"),20), SPEC = rep(c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"),10)))
mydf$dates <- seq(as.Date("2014-09-01"), by=1, length.out=25)
mydf$x <- as.numeric(rnorm(100))
mydf$z <- as.numeric(rnorm(100))
mydf$deltaxz <- mydf$x-mydf$z
before=as.Date("2014-09-11")
after=as.Date("2014-09-03")

mydf=mydf[mydf$dates<=before & mydf$dates>=after,]
```

What I want is to get the following trellis objects for each COD in the dataframe:

```
graph1 <- xyplot (deltaxz ~ dates | SPEC, data=df, type=c("p","g"), col=c("black"), layout=c(1,3))
graph2 <- xyplot (1/deltaxz ~ dates | SPEC, data=df, type=c("p","g"), col=c("red"), layout=c(1,3))
```

What I thought was to apply the useful `plyr` functions, and my choice was `d_ply` so I wrote the following lines:

```
graph1 <- function(df) {assign("graph.1", xyplot (deltaxz ~ dates | SPEC, data=df, type=c("p","g"), col=c("black"), layout=c(1,3)), envir=.GlobalEnv)}
graph2 <- function(df) {assign("graph.2", xyplot (1/deltaxz ~ dates | SPEC, data=df, type=c("p","g"), col=c("red"), layout=c(1,3)), envir=.GlobalEnv)}
```

Now if I try to use the functions above combined with `d_ply`, I don't get a trellis object, but a null object:

```
graphic1 <- d_ply(mydf, .(mydf$COD), graph1, .print=T)
graphic2 <- d_ply(mydf, .(mydf$COD), graph2, .print=T)
```

The reason I need two trellis object is because I want to plot them one under the other to show something (that is evident using the actual sales figures but not the dummy dataframe). This will be a different challenge, so for now I stick to my request.
Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance,
MZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what's with assign() in the graph1/graph2 functions? That seems completely unnecessary. So just change those to

```
graph1 <- function(df) {xyplot (deltaxz ~ dates | SPEC, data=df, type=c("p","g"), col=c("black"), layout=c(1,3))}
graph2 <- function(df) {xyplot (1/deltaxz ~ dates | SPEC, data=df, type=c("p","g"), col=c("red"), layout=c(1,3))}
```

and secondly, the `d_ply` is specifically intended to return nothing (NULL). If you want to gather the results in a list, then use

```
graphic1 <- dlply(mydf, .(mydf$COD), graph1)
graphic2 <- dlply(mydf, .(mydf$COD), graph2)
```

Then you can get at the individual graphs with `graphic1$AB` and so on.

Comment: Thanks MrFlick! 
Now I see it was pretty easy but I was so stubborn that I didn't want to change my previous coding (or better, I was unsure what to touch in it).
I will now try to plot them together in a sensible way, probably using `l_ply`
Thanks again!